# Authorization-Heades for Google Data (Calendar) API request

Tags: android, authentication, google-calendar-api, google-data-api

I want to be able to retrieve a users calendar and events from the Google Calendar API. Basically I managed to get an Auth-Token from Android's AccountManager and do the request, but I get

```
  "error": {
    "errors": [
    {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
    }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }
    }
```

As a response. The code producing it is (partial). When running this for the first time, Android asked me to authorize Access to my calendar data for my app, which I accepted.

```
    final Account account = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google")[0];

    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture =
            manager.getAuthToken(account, "cl", true,
                    new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                            try {
                                Bundle bundle = future.getResult();

                                if (bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN)) {

                                    final String authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                                    final Uri usersCalendars = Uri.parse(
                                            "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList")
                                            .buildUpon()
                                            .appendQueryParameter("key","--myapikey--")
                                            .build();

                                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(usersCalendars.toString());

                                    request.setHeader("Authorization","GoogleLoginAuth=" + authToken);
                                    request.setHeader("GData-Version","3.0");

                                    HttpResponse response =  client.execute(request);

                                    // outputting response, logging etc
```

As you can see I am not using the google-api-java-client, because I could not get that one to fly either. Basically the example code calls methods that do not exist anymore / are moved to Android's AccountManager and the android-calendar-example produced a 401 eror instead of listing my calendars.

If you guys have any hints, documentation etc. I'd be glad.

*edit* I just tried invalidating the token via

```
manager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google",authToken);
```

then retrieving a new one via, with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space in b/w the Authorization header value - `"GoogleLogin auth=xxxxxxx".`